# Openfire Xmpp Chat not working with SSL enabled

Tags: php, xmpp

We are using Openfire Xmpp chat with web (conversjs) it was working fine when SSL was not enabled/installed. After we enabled SSL (HTTPS) the chat stopped working. Unable to connect to Openfire server.

Answer (score 0):

After having Secure Site, you will need to change bind URL as well with "https".

Comment: Yes we bind with https